# ANDROID -> transparent background for imageview

Tags: android, background, imageview, png, transparent

In my application I have a `CameraPreview`. I would like to add an imageView over it so I need the imageView to have a transparent background. The src of the imageView will be a png so I could see the CameraPreview underneath.

However, it's like I've tried everything to manage the background of the `ImageView` Transparent:

- change the alpha value (in the code AND in the xml file)
- change the background to @null then to `#00000000` (in the code AND in the xml file for both)

But it still not work !

Did I miss anything ?

Please ask if you need parts of my code.
P

Comment: Make your `Src Image Background Transparent`

Comment: set android:background="@android:color/transparent"  in xml filr

Comment: could you post your code? that you have tried yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks for your answears but I have managed to solve my problem:
I gave a random color to the background of my layout (for example #FF34035544) and I changed the two first letters to 00 which made #0034035544.
It was finally very simple !